# How to read 2 digit integer from getchar fn?

Tags: c

The code given below is what i was trying to achieve.

The idea is user will enter the value as long as he don't press enter two times;  when he does the values gets displayed, but when 2 digit values are entered it only returns a single value because of `getchar` limitation, how to achieve the same thing but also read both digits?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int ptr[3][18];
void main()
{       
    printf("\n  Add a digit or DOUBLE Press enter to display values\n");
    int i=1,j,a=1,c=1,b,d,e,z=1;
    if(i<=a)
    scanf("%d",&ptr[1][i]);
    me1:
    ++i;
    b=getchar();
    if(b=='\n')
    {
        d=getchar();
        if(d=='\n')
        {
            goto me2;
        }
        else
        {
            e=d-'0';
            ptr[1][i]=e;
            z++;
            goto me1;
        }
    }
    me2:
    for(j=1;j<=z;j++)
    {
        printf("ptr[1][%d]= %d\n",j,ptr[1][j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Call it in a loop and collect the values in an array, or you could apply what you seem to already know how to do (if you actually wrote this code) and use the `scanf` function.  I would get rid of the labels and the `goto` statements.  The use of labels and goto statements leads to spaghetti code.  And learn to use proper indentation and bracing.

Comment: I can't use scanf because it skips over leading whitespace and wait some non-whitespace text. That not what I want to achieve through this program. For example:The user enter a no. 23 the no. is then stored in an array now what will the scanf do if the user don't want to enter any more input user pressses enter which should the display the no. but that doesnt happen due to scanf the input wants some no whitespace text which is not i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Never use getchar() after scanf(). Because scanf() reads the stdin stream till it encounters a newline escape character. It will ignore the newline character in the stdin. So, you will need to put a redundant "getchar()" just to read that "\n"

Comment: scanf() is executed when a non-whitespace text followed by whitespace is pressed right ! Here the first index of ptr [1][1] stores the first input using scanf() now i want to read the next number so i give another input lets say 12 using scanf it do stores the input this first case ,NOW, what if after the first index stores the value the user dont want to store any more value so when he presses enter key the input should stop taking values and display the value stored.

Comment: If you are having issue understanding my problem try running the code and enter only 1 digit value as long as you want and check for the output and then do the same for 2 digit values and see for yourself.